# How do I eliminate SKScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit cutting off on all 4 sides with rotation?

Tags: swift, skscene

**How do I eliminate SKScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit cutting off on all four sides with rotation?**

I read elsewhere:

```
.aspectFit Scales the content to fill the size of the view. 
Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.
```

I call `setupScene()` **from within** `override func viewDidLoad() {..}`

**In** my `func setupScene() {..}` I call:

```
if let ourScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "aName") {

    ourScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

}
```

And, indeed, a portion of the content **is** clipped to fill the view’s bounds. Resizing between Landscape and Portrait does happen as it should .. but the clipping on top and bottom happens.

I do note that there is zero clipping horizontally, but just vertically:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

FWIW, I have used `.aspectFill` which renders a significant improvement, but clipping still occurs, albeit **much** less than with `.aspectFit`.

Finally, it is significant that my SKScenes are much taller than wide - and this may be the source of my problem.

Which begs the question, should I redesign my SKScenes to be **square** and **not rectangular**? I just do not know.

Any guidance as to how I can avoid cutoff and instead have the whole `SKScene` resized to the entire SKView, whether it's in Landscape or Portrait mode with zero cut off?

**OR** do I just elect `AppleTV` as the only destination because of the rectangular shape? I think this is an easy way out that just avoids having to find the real solution! .. **so, no thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

**BINGO!!**

1. A Game which height is much greater than its width.
2. If I allow .aspectFill to literally do its thing, cutoff will occur as already stated above. This makes sense because literally squeezing a tall height into Landscape mode would make all the enclosed Game Pieces super super tiny. Ugly to say the least.
3. I literally thought of this "by accident" .. namely, when the user rotates their Device 90 degrees to Landscape, do rotate the Game Scene, but do **not** scrunch the size of all the enclosed Game Pieces and do **not** change their positions.

Keep these Game Pieces scaled and positioned as if they were still in Portrait mode even though the Device is physically in Landscape mode.

Analogy = when you cut down a tree, it goes from Portrait to Landscape, but the tree does **not** become shorter when on the ground.

So, go to Info and Custom iOS Target Properties and look for this:

[image: Custom iOS Target Properties]

ASAMOF, you can now eliminate any call to .aspectFill or .aspectFit

[image: The rotated Scene]

Remember this is a Game targeted for use with a Gamepad. Do you really want to be scrolling while your nifty Game Piece is trying to avoid hitting a barrier?

**BINGO!**